# How do I generate an Array string from an array in memory (php)

Tags: php, arrays, code-generation, shortcut

I need to create a big array in my code, I have the values in several tables (for easy management). I select it and now I have all the values in an array, in memory in the way I want. My problem, I need to write this array down, into the code. Is there a way to take an array which sits in the memory and translate it into a string "array('g'=>'h','b'=>'d'....)" which I can then echo and just copy-paste into my code?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know all of PHP functions...for the down-voters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function. From the manual:

```
<?php
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
var_export($a);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
)
```

Comment: var_export is a quick debugging gem along with it's second argument

Answer (score -3):

Check out [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Comment: both `var_dump` and `print_r` do not output valid php - they are purely for debugging